# Getting error as unknown keyword ssl in haproxy configuration file

Tags: ssl, haproxy

This is my haproxy.cfg file

```
global
    daemon
    maxconn 256

defaults
    mode tcp
    timeout connect 5000ms
    timeout client 50000ms
    timeout server 50000ms


frontend ft_ssltests
        mode tcp
        bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/sslkeys/host.crt ca-file /etc/haproxy/sslkeys/host.pem
        default_backend webmail


backend webmail
        balance roundrobin
        server server1 10.198.2.76:50000 maxconn 32 check
        server server2 10.198.2.76:60000 maxconn 32 check
```

After restarting above config file I am getting error as shown below

```
service haproxy restart
[ALERT] 023/230240 (4375) : parsing [/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:14] : 'bind *:443' unknown keyword 'ssl'. Registered keywords :
    [ TCP] defer-accept
    [ TCP] interface <arg>
    [ TCP] mss <arg>
    [ TCP] transparent
    [ TCP] v4v6
    [ TCP] v6only
    [STAT] level <arg>
    [UNIX] gid <arg>
    [UNIX] group <arg>
    [UNIX] mode <arg>
    [UNIX] uid <arg>
    [UNIX] user <arg>
    [ ALL] accept-proxy
    [ ALL] backlog <arg>
    [ ALL] id <arg>
    [ ALL] maxconn <arg>
    [ ALL] name <arg>
    [ ALL] nice <arg>
    [ ALL] process <arg>
[ALERT] 023/230240 (4375) : Error(s) found in configuration file : /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
[ALERT] 023/230240 (4375) : Fatal errors found in configuration.
Errors found in configuration file, check it with 'haproxy check'.
```

Please help me to find the solution...

Answer (score 19):

haproxy supports SSL starting with version 1.5.
Check which version you are running and if SSL support has been compiled.  Type :

```
$ haproxy -vv
HA-Proxy version 1.6.3 2015/12/25
[...]
Built with OpenSSL version : OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
Running on OpenSSL version : OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
OpenSSL library supports TLS extensions : yes
OpenSSL library supports SNI : yes
OpenSSL library supports prefer-server-ciphers : yes
[...]
```

to check these two mandatory things.

Comment: This should be marked as the answer. OP, give some credit.

Comment: I have a newer version (like 1.9.8), but I'm also getting this error.

Answer (score 4):

Install haproxy by below command with ssl switch:

make -j 4 TARGET=linux2628 USE_NS=1 USE_TFO=1 **USE_OPENSSL=1** USE_ZLIB=1  USE_PCRE=1  **SSL_INC=/usr/local/openssl/include SSL_LIB=/usr/local/openssl/lib**

Answer (score 1):

- HAProxy needs to be built with `SSL_INC` and `SSL_LIB` flag options for TLS/SSL support
- In my Centos7 OS VM, `openssl-devel` package also had to be installed apart from  `gcc pcre-devel tar make`  packages as a prerequisite

  > `sudo yum install -y openssl-devel gcc pcre-devel tar make`
- build

  > `make TARGET=linux-glibc  USE_PCRE=1  USE_OPENSSL=1  SSL_INC=/usr/local/openssl/include SSL_LIB=/usr/local/openssl/lib`

Just FYI: In debian based(ubuntu kind of) you need to install openssl  with this command

> `sudo apt-get install libssl-dev`